# How to Add asp:silverlight in ToolBox Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: .net, asp.net, silverlight

I am using VS2008,I can not able to see the asp:silverlight (to embed my silverlight file in aspx page) ,

How can i get it in my toolbox.

Comment: asp:silverlight in toolbox...Please be clear ???? Do you have Silverlight installed. Install silverlight before using its controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asp:Silverlight control is no longer included as of Silverlight 3.  In order to include a Silverlight app in a web page you will need to use the html `<object>` tag.

Your silverlight application project will have created a Test page (.aspx or .htm) either in the output folder or in a Web application is associated with it in the solution.  You can use copy the object tag contents from these to use elsewhere.

Comment: i need to access the Method present in silverlight(.xap) from Javascript,How can i do it ,Could you please send some link.

Comment: @Ramakrishnan:  Sounds like an entirely different question from the above, however try this:- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221414%28VS.95%29.aspx